# How to Convert a Byte Array to String for a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, arrays, converters

I have a Domain Class User with the Following properties (Fields):

```
UserId (int)
UserName (nvarchar(25))
SecurePassword (varbinary(32))
Salt (varbinary(32))
```

SecurePassword and Salt store a byte array with a length of 32 as you may have guessed.
If I set my

```
BindingSource.DataSource = context.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
```

And then my

```
DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSource;
```

I’ll get an Error telling me to Handle the DataError Event for the GridView.
Once I do that with an empty method the SecurePassword and Salt Columns show [X] for every row.

Now, I could use linq to render that in an anonymous type as:

```
 var data = from u in context.Users
            select new
            {
                u.UserId,
                u.UserName,
                SecurePassword = BitConverter.ToString(u.SecurePassword),
                Salt = BitConverter.ToString(u.Salt)
            };
```

But I really don’t want an anonymous type.
In WPF I could have written a Converter that inherits from IValueConverter, but that doesn’t seem to be available in WinForms.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CellFormatting event. Something like:

```
void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // 2 - Salt, 3 - SecurePassword
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            byte[] array = (byte[])e.Value;
            e.Value = BitConverter.ToString(array);
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        else
            e.FormattingApplied = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt answer that work very well. I did need to set AutoGenerateColumns to false and add Columns manually. Still, it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

To build upon the other answer, the simplest way I achieved this was:

1. Go into Properties of your DataGridView, find the Columns property, edit it, and change the ColumnType of your binary columns to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.
2. Go into the Events pane and generate a method on the CellFormatting event.
3. Set the code of the method to be something like:

---

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            e.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[]) e.Value);
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        else
            e.FormattingApplied = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when binding to a table with byte data in it so I wrote the following method that creates a new text column, adds it to the table, copies over the data from the byte column while converting it to a string, moves the new column to the position of the old column, and deletes the old column

Here is the code in vb

```
Private Sub ReplaceByteColumns(table As DataTable)
    Dim byteColumns As New Dictionary(Of DataColumn, DataColumn)
    For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns
        If column.DataType = GetType(Byte()) Then
            Dim byteColumn As New DataColumn
            byteColumn.DataType = GetType(String)
            byteColumns.Add(column, byteColumn)
        End If
    Next

    For Each column As DataColumn In byteColumns.Keys
        Dim byteColumn As DataColumn = byteColumns(column)
        table.Columns.Add(byteColumn)
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            row.Item(byteColumn) = BitConverter.ToString(CType(row.Item(column), Byte()))
        Next
        byteColumn.SetOrdinal(column.Ordinal)
        byteColumn.ReadOnly = True
        table.Columns.Remove(column)
        byteColumn.ColumnName = column.ColumnName
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the code auto converted to C# using https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

```
private void ReplaceByteColumns(DataTable table) {
    Dictionary<DataColumn, DataColumn> byteColumns = new Dictionary<DataColumn, DataColumn>();
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
        if ((column.DataType == typeof(byte[]))) {
            DataColumn byteColumn = new DataColumn();
            byteColumn.DataType = typeof(string);
            byteColumns.Add(column, byteColumn);
        }

    }

    foreach (DataColumn column in byteColumns.Keys) {
        DataColumn byteColumn = byteColumns[column];
        table.Columns.Add(byteColumn);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
            row.Item[byteColumn] = BitConverter.ToString(((byte[])(row.Item[column])));
        }

        byteColumn.SetOrdinal(column.Ordinal);
        byteColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        table.Columns.Remove(column);
        byteColumn.ColumnName = column.ColumnName;
    }

}
```