# Changing the back colour on a specific row of a Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to change the back colour with a condition as follows. It doesn't work.

```
private void frmJobStat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sql = "SELECT `jobno` AS JOB_NO,`lcode` AS LOCATION,iscompleted, iscannotrepair, isissued FROM `jobmaster`";
    config.Load_DTG(sql, dgvJobNo);

    dgvJobNo.Columns[1].Visible = false;
    //dgvJobNo.Columns[2].Visible = false;
    //dgvJobNo.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    //dgvJobNo.Columns[4].Visible = false;
    dgvJobNo.Columns[0].Width = 100;
    dgvJobNo.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "000000";

    for (int i = 0; i < dgvJobNo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Boolean.Parse(dgvJobNo.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
        {
            dgvJobNo.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }

    //foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgvJobNo.Rows)
    //{
    //    if (rw.Cells[2].Value.ToString()=="1")
    //    {
    //        dgvJobNo.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    //    }
    //}
}
```

I have load one column from a table with true/false values. I need to change the colour when it is true.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is this code executed? It appears to work as expected. Have you put a breakpoint on the line… `dgvJobNo.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;` … to see if the parse is ever successful?

Comment: I executed in form load event. But not working.

Comment: Often Load is too early.

Comment: Assuming… _”It doesn't work.”_ … means you get no errors, then I would suggest you put a breakpoint on the `if` statement and carefully examine what … `dgvJobNo.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()` … is returning. I am just saying, that using `Boolean.Parse` would throw a format exception if the cells value was NOT a valid `Boolean` value. In addition, if “know” there are `true` values in the cells, this would be a good debugging starting point.

Comment: See [RowPrePaint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614471/5045688) event. Also see [CellFormatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32104032/5045688) event.

Answer (score 1):

People who use a DataGridView quite often tend to directly fiddle with Cells and how values are displayed. It is way easier to use DataBinding: separate the data from the way that it is displayed using `DataGridView.DataSource`.

### Use the DataSource

I haven't got the faintest Idea what you are showing in your DataGridView, so let's assume you want to show Products.

So somewhere you have a class to save and retrieve Products from some place. Of course you hide that the data is fetched from a database, and how this is fetched (DbConnection and DbCommand? Or maybe entity framework and LINQ?). All you know is that you can store Products and retrieve them later on:

```
interface IRepository
{
    int AddProduct(Product product)   // returns Id
    Product FetchProduct(int id);

    IEnumerable<Product> FetchProducts(...); // fetches several Products to display
    ...
```

Oh, before I forget:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public int Stock {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Suppose you have a form with a DataGridView where you want to show some Products. Using visual studio designer you have added a DataGridView and some columns

In the constructor:

```
public MyForm : ...
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Id);
    this.columnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.columnPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Price);
    ...
}
```

Of course you have access to the repository and a method that fetches the Products that you want to show:

```
private IRepository ProductRepository => ...

private IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductsToDisplay()
{
    return this.ProductRepository.FetchProducts(...);
}
```

Now to display the fetched Products, we use the DataSource of the DataGridView in a BindingList:

```
private BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

private void ShowInitialProducts()
{
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>( this.FetchProductsToDisplay().ToList());
```

And of course, while Loading the form:

```
private void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ShowInitialProducts();
}
```

This is enough to show all Products. If the operator Adds or Removes some rows, or edits the values of the rows, they are automatically updated. If the operator indicates that he has finished editing the Products, for instance by clicking OK button:

```
private void OnButtonOkClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ProcessEditedProducts();
}

private void ProcessEditedProducts()
{
    ICollection<Product> displayedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts();
    // find out which Products are added / removed / changed
    this.ProcessProducts(displayedProducts);
}
```

By the way, did you notice that my procedures are always very small: they do only one thing, they serve one purpose. This makes them easy to understand, good to reuse, easy to test and to change.

### Intermezzo: some useful functions

The following small methods might be handy. If you have a DataGridViewRow, you can get `DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` to get the Product that is shown in the Row.

```
// Get the Product that is displayed in row with rowIndex
private Product DisplayedProduct(int rowIndex)
{
    return (Product)this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem;
}

// Get the Currently Selected Product
private Product CurrentProduct()
{
    return (Product)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
}

// Get all Selected Products (if you allow multi-selecting
private IEnumerable<Product> GetSelectedProducts()
{
    return this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
        .Cast<Product>();
}
```

### Back to your question

Apparently, there is a predicate which makes that you want to give some Cells a different background Color. For example: if the stock is zero, you want it red, and if the stock is low, you want it orange. Otherwise you want a white background

```
Color ZeroStockColor = Color.Red;
Color LowStockColor = Color.Orange;
int LowStockValue = 10;               // 10 or less: Stock is low
```

Just before the value of a cell is displayed, you get the chance to format the cell, using event [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).

If the column that shows the Stock is being formatted, we want to check the Value of the Stock. If it is zero, we want red background, if it is low, we have an orange background.

```
private void OnCellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // e contains the rowIndex and columnIndex
    if (e.ColumnIndex = this.columnStockValue.Index)
    {
        // Formatting the cell that contains the stock value
        Product productToFormat = this.DisplayedProduct(e.RowIndex);
        DataGridViewCell cellToFormat = this.dataGridView1
            .Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        if (productToFormat.Stock == 0)
        {
            // no stock: RED!
            cellToFormat.Style.BackColor = ZeroStockColor;
        }
        else if (productToFormat.Stock <= LowStockValue)
        {
            // Low stock: Orange!
            cellToFormat.Style.BackColor = LowStockColor;
        }
        else
        {
            // enough stock: use default cell Style of this column
            cellToFormat.Style =  null;
        }
    }
}
```

If a `DataGridViewCell.Style` is not null, then this Style is used to format the cell. if the Style is null, then `DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle` is used, unless that value is also null. In that case we go even higher: `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle`

### Conclusion

If you use DataBinding, it is easy to show your data in the DataGridView and to access the objects in the DataGridView: the current one, the selected ones or the one that is displayed in the 10th row.

To format a cell, use `DataGridViewCell.Style`, or the DefaultCellStyle in the column, or in the DataGridView

Use event `DataGridView.CellFormatting` to format the cell just before it will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I am a beginner for c#. Still I am learning. I am trying to follow your suggetions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because in C#, if you create a new object just by assignment, it will not generate child references so

```
 dgvJobNo.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
```

could be non existent here.

You have to do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvJobNo.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Boolean.Parse(dgvJobNo.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()))
            {
var row= new Rows();
var a = new DefaultCellStyle();
a.BackColor= Color.Blue;
row.DefaultCellStyle = a;
                dgvJobNo.Rows[i] = row;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I mean no disrespect, however… your code is not even valid C# .Net code. Also I do not agree with your statement… Why would you say… `dgvJobNo.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` … _“could be non existent here.”_ … ? … If it didn’t exist, you would get a `null` reference exception or index out of bounds exception. The OP’s posted code works and unless the parse is failing for some reason… something else is going on.

Comment: could be a case, I used to do it like this and it worked for me. I don't have the exact solution here but just sharing the basic idea of how it might work. Generally, it doesn't throw a null reference error because there is nothing to refer to. And I used to create models to bind data in structure.

Comment: _”Generally, it doesn't throw a null reference error because there is nothing to refer to.”_ … ? …

Comment: it doesn't work sir., this is says  dgvJobNo.Rows[i] = row;     read only

Comment: When I call in the  dgvJobNo_CellFormatting   event, it works.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnG , In C# when I create an object of class, it creates an object with only direct child references. for eg. public class User { public Name userName {get;set;}} public class Name { public string firstName {get;set;} public string lastName {get;set;} public string middleName {get;set;}}
If I create var user = new User(); it will have  user.userName but user.userName.firstName ; user.userName.middleName will not be created by default.